# Restored monerujo wallet key file and password is not working. What could it be?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, monerujo, android-wallet

I have a monerujo wallet I have used frequently to send and receive. I tried restoring this wallet and key file to another monerujo wallet but the password is not working. The original monerujo wallet I was using stopped working for whatever reason, which is why i copied the wallet files out. I even tried to use this wallet file on the monero windows client and still says incorrect password. I've been using the same password all this time.

Also I have the backup seed too, but when I restore this seed. The address is completely different from what I have on the monerujo wallet originally.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason the wallet cache file was corrupt on my monerujo app. A monero wallet consist of 2 files:

- wallet file (wallet_file)
- wallet key file (wallet_file.keys)

However, when using the wallet files from monerujo on desktop or cli, it sets the password to something else vs what you use in the mobile app. This is called CrazyPass, which is a long 20-30 character alphanumeric password that looks something like this (spaces included):

XX55 ARPT R3QH Z97K XXXX WTCK LSPK YYA2A FBC2 Y4DD XXXX XXXX GYS3

When opening a corrupt cache wallet file on the desktop, it will throw an error. The only solution here is to delete the wallet_file, but not the keys file. It will regenerate when you open the wallet_file again using your keys file.